# Displaying complex data in jquery datatable

Tags: typescript, datatables

I have an object like this,

```
 class DataView  {

        public Name: string = null;    
        public DataDateTime: string = null;    
        public Counts: DataCount[] = [];    
        public TotalCount: DataTotal = null;
    }

    class DataCount{
        public UserCount: number = 0;
        public SearchCount: number = 0;
        ....
        ....
     }
```

Using jquery datatable, I want to display the following information,

a. Name property
b. All the fields in Counts property
c. DataDateTime property

All of the above should display in a single table,

I have tried as shown below,

```
   columns: [
                  { title: "Name", data: "Name" },
                  { title: "User Count", data: "Counts.UserCount" },
                    ...
             ],
```

But, I am not seeing data. How should I define the data attribute in jquery datatable columns so that I can see the data as expected.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/guidance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you are using to build the object but it looks like it should match what you defined in your table.  How are you adding the data to Datatables?  In most cases Datatables expects an array of objects even if just one.  Maybe you can post your full Datatables init code along with an example of the JSON data returned from the server.  Here is an example from the Datatables site: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html

Comment: I am using the jquery datatable's AddRows method. Instead of passing an array, i am passing the whole object (in my case, the DataView   object). Also, I am trying to build the column as shown in the example: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html but, no luck so far. I will try to create a fiddler for replicating this issue.

Comment: add.rows() expects an array of objects.  Please see the [Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types) documentation for more info.